# How do I change from Ubuntu 18.04 to Lubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates, lubuntu

How can one change from Ubuntu 18.04 to Lubuntu 18.04 through the terminal? what is the code?

Comment: These flavours only vary in their default desktop environment

Comment: The official flavors can be installed from ubuntu like following: `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` same goes for others like kubuntu-desktop or xubuntu-desktop. You get the idea.

Be aware that installing an other/additional desktop might change your installation in unexpected ways (Greeters change, Bootscreen changes, default apps change, etc.). For a clean system it is recommended to install the desired desktop from the beginning, but for experimentation, this is quite convenient.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

will install the lubuntu desktop and all its standard applications. After executing the command, log out and on the log-in screen, use the cog to select the Lubuntu session and then provide your password to log in to the Lubuntu desktop.

There is, perhaps unfortunately, no standard way to cleanly remove anything related to the Ubuntu desktop to leave only the Lubuntu packages.